# Problema en servidor con signalr en ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

tengo una aplicación donde uso signalr en .NET MVC 5, el problema es que en tanto en mi servidor local como en el de mis colaboradores funciona pero en el servidor me muestra un error 403:
{dominio} /signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B"name"%3A"chathub"%7D%5D&_=1607403959931

Estas son mis configuraciones:

- Startup.cs

```
namespace WebApp4A
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Y no sé si tenga que hacer alguna configuración extra en los scripts o en el servidor, la verdad ya estoy bastante desesperado, muchas gracias.